# cannot resolve explode due to type mismatch in spark while parsing xml file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-xml

I have a data frame with below schema

```
root
 |-- DataPartition: long (nullable = true)
 |-- TimeStamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _organizationId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- _segmentId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- seg:BusinessSegments: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- seg:BusinessSegment: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _hierarchicalCode: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _industryId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _ranking: long (nullable = true)
 |-- seg:GeographicSegments: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- seg:GeographicSegment: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _geographyId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- seg:IsSubtracted: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- seg:Sequence: long (nullable = true)
 |-- seg:IsCorporate: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- seg:IsElimination: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- seg:IsOperatingSegment: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- seg:IsOther: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- seg:IsShariaCompliant: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- seg:PredecessorSegments: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- seg:PredecessorSegment: long (nullable = true)
 |-- seg:SegmentLocalLanguageLabel: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _languageId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- seg:SegmentName: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _languageId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- seg:SegmentType: string (nullable = true)
 |-- seg:SegmentTypeId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- seg:ValidFromPeriodEndDate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _action: string (nullable = true)
```

Now I want to get `seg:BusinessSegments.seg:BusinessSegment` value from the schema.

But my issue is when I do this using explode

```
val GeographicSegmentchildDF = parentDF.select($"DataPartition".as("DataPartition"), $"TimeStamp".as("TimeStamp"), $"_organizationId", $"_segmentId", explode($"seg:GeographicSegments.seg:GeographicSegment").as("GeographicSegments"), $"_action")
val GeographicSegmentchildArrayDF = GeographicSegmentchildDF.select(getDataPartition($"DataPartition").as("DataPartition"), $"TimeStamp".as("TimeStamp"), $"_organizationId".as("OrganizationId"), $"_segmentId".as("SegmentId"), $"GeographicSegments.*", getFFActionChild($"_action").as("FFAction|!|"))
```

So in first line I am exploding and in the next line I am doing * or expand on that `$"GeographicSegments.*",` .

I get error like 
This is what I am doing

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   cannot resolve
>   'explode(`seg:GeographicSegments`.`seg:GeographicSegment`)' due to
>   data type mismatch:

I know the issue because in schema I get `seg:GeographicSegment` as struct not as array and that is why I am getting .

So the real issue is I don't have fixed schema .

**When there are two records in xml file then `seg:GeographicSegment` becomes as array and then my code is working fine but when I get only one record then it work as struct and my code fails .**

How can I handle this in my code .
Do I have to put condition while parsing schema ?
Or is there anyway I

Here is one of the case which is not working

```
val columnTypePredecessorSegments = parentDF.select($"seg:PredecessorSegments.seg:PredecessorSegment").schema.map(_.dataType).head.toString().startsWith("LongType")
    //if column type is struct then use .* and array function to convert the struct to array else just use array
    val PredecessorSegmentschildDF = if (columnTypePredecessorSegments) {
      parentDF.select($"DataPartition".as("DataPartition"), $"TimeStamp".as("TimeStamp"), $"_organizationId", $"_segmentId", explode(array($"seg:PredecessorSegments.seg:PredecessorSegment")).as("PredecessorSegments"), $"_action")
    } else {
      parentDF.select($"DataPartition".as("DataPartition"), $"TimeStamp".as("TimeStamp"), $"_organizationId", $"_segmentId", explode($"seg:PredecessorSegments.seg:PredecessorSegment").as("PredecessorSegments"), $"_action")
    }
    val PredecessorSegmentsDFFinalChilddDF = PredecessorSegmentschildDF.select(getDataPartition($"DataPartition").as("DataPartition"), $"TimeStamp".as("TimeStamp"), $"_organizationId".as("OrganizationId"), $"_segmentId".as("SuccessorSegment"), $"PredecessorSegments.*", getFFActionChild($"_action").as("FFAction|!|"))
    PredecessorSegmentsDFFinalChilddDF.show(false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > When there are two records in xml file then seg:GeographicSegment becomes as array and then my code is working fine but when I get only one record then it work as struct and my code fails .

Then you would need to *check for the datatype of the column before using explode*

```
//checking for struct or array type in that column
val columnType = parentDF.select($"seg:GeographicSegments.seg:GeographicSegment").schema.map(_.dataType).head.toString().startsWith("StructType")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
//if column type is struct then use .* and array function to convert the struct to array else just use array
val GeographicSegmentchildDF = if(columnType) {
  parentDF.select($"DataPartition".as("DataPartition"), $"TimeStamp".as("TimeStamp"), $"_organizationId", $"_segmentId", explode(array($"seg:GeographicSegments.seg:GeographicSegment.*")).as("GeographicSegments"), $"_action")
}
else {
  parentDF.select($"DataPartition".as("DataPartition"), $"TimeStamp".as("TimeStamp"), $"_organizationId", $"_segmentId", explode($"seg:GeographicSegments.seg:GeographicSegment").as("GeographicSegments"), $"_action")
}
val GeographicSegmentchildArrayDF = GeographicSegmentchildDF.select(getDataPartition($"DataPartition").as("DataPartition"), $"TimeStamp".as("TimeStamp"), $"_organizationId".as("OrganizationId"), $"_segmentId".as("SegmentId"), $"GeographicSegments.*", getFFActionChild($"_action").as("FFAction|!|"))
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: I am getting error `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can only star expand struct data types. Attribute: `ArrayBuffer(PredecessorSegments)`;` when I do same thing for `seg:PredecessorSegments`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply ..I have updated in the question because in comment section it wont look good ..

Comment: @AtharvThakur, the updated code is checking for LongType which is different from the original problem. Its for sure that the solution will not work as explode is useful for array or map. And you will have to try another technique for that datatype. May be another question can help you get the answer. :)